# Remove TFS Name from server list Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

When I am removing `tfs` from TFS Server list it show me the "Remove" option as disabled. So how to remove it from the list?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkBsE.png]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Which version/edition of VS do you use? Are you able to access the server from web portal? Are you able to see the Remove option enabled after the refresh completed?

Comment: VS 2017 and when we refresh list of server name vanished after few seconds.

Comment: You could check this server, it may doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could check this server to see whether you can access it from web portal, this server may doesn't exist.